# jquery insert div element which will include all old body content

Tags: jquery

hi i want to insert div element in the root of my page hierarchy, so it must be opened after body tag and closed before body close tag, how can i do it in jquery?

Comment: the root of the page IMO is the `HTML` tag and not the body. although I too think it's the `DOCTYPE`. But still it's not the body. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
<body>
   <div>
   <!-- old contents -->
   </div>
</body>
```

you can do it this way,

```
$(function(){
   $('body').contents().wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

it seems you have accepted this one so I just want to add something.

you may also add some class to the div you have just added.

like this,

```
$(function(){
   $('body').contents().wrapAll('<div class="someClass"></div>');
});
```

Comment: And suddenly, all becomes sense :p

Comment: @jAndy, yeah, but don't worry, at first I did also got the same assumption and got confused by the OP as you did I guess... and maybe I'm still wrong.. ;)